# Please explain the rules of differentiation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I have an equation $f(x)=3\sqrt{\ x}$ and i have to find the derivative of the function f.

What i have gotten so far is $3x^{-1/2}$, which then comes out to be ${3/2}x^{-3/2}$.

I know the answer is f'(x)=$3\over 2\sqrt{\ x}$

I just can't figure out how to get that answer from ${3/2}\over x^{3/2}$ to f'(x)=$3\over 2\sqrt{\ x}$.

Can someone please explain so I can better understand? Thanks

Comment: The function is $3\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a little mistake.

$f(x)=3\sqrt{x}=3x^{1/2}$, not $3x^{-1/2}$.

Hence $f'(x)=\frac{3}2x^{-1/2}=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: oh thank you that makes a big difference. Thank you

Comment: @CMLara note that $\frac{d}{dx} (3x^{\frac{-1}{2}})$ is $- \frac {3}{2}x^{\frac{-3}{2}}$

Comment: @CMLara If the question has been answered, you can click the green 'answered' button :)

Comment: @hippalectryon it's making me wait.. I will once i can sorry